# GRAKN Server start fails right after install

Tags: vaticle-typedb, knowledge-graph

Installed Grakn-Core as per their instruction on the website via Homebrew (Mac OS). As I am trying to start the Grakn server by executing `grakn server start` I am consistently getting the following error:

[image]

Same goes for any other command argument after `grakn server <arg>`. Did something change and is not reflected in the documentation or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you're using the 2.0.0-alpha version of Grakn core, for which the docs live at [dev.docs.grakn.ai](http://dev.docs.grakn.ai) (as opposed to dev.grakn.ai, which is for the 1.8.4 docs)

The url will be changed to our main docs page once we're out of alpha!